# How to (easily) get the back cover off a $35 Polaroid PER7021 e-reader?

Tags: battery, ebook-readers

I have an e-reader I picked up at Big Lots for $35 and it's a great machine, aside from two problems:

1. It eats through batteries when turned off.
2. The battery cover doesn't remove easily without using a butter knife.

I think that the former problem could be resolved if I could just take care of the latter problem.

What do you do about this fellow PER7021 e-readers?

Comment: Is the reader PER7021 or PER702 (I can't find anything about PER7021)?

Comment: One reason that products like this go to clearance stores like biglots is that they have quality issues.  It seems that some of these function just fine while some do not.  You could probably take the reader back to big lots and get it replaced if they still have them.

Answer (score 3):

Try using an iSesamo — it's a tool explicitly made for popping open the panels on electronic devices ([www.newertech.com/products/isesamo.php](http://www.newertech.com/products/isesamo.php))

The iSesamo is thinner than plastic spludgers and sits in a sweet spot between stiff/inflexible and too-bendable-to-pry-things-off.

[image]